Making conjunction between instances and objects nice
I'm looking for a way to make the connection between instance and object in geometry nodes appear more natural. The edge at the connection is often hard, straight and artificial. I know that the impression can be improved using the material shader or material displacement, but I would like to find a way to add a kind of additional geometry at the connection/ conjunction.
Does someone have any experience or idea about this issue?


Hi, like I said, i am searching for a way to make the conjunction „ more natural“ looking. Not by material, by geometry. Usually the result looks like on the image, sticks on TOP of each other.
To be even more precise, it should be like a irregular „extrude mesh node“ with adjustable random effect. - or some geometry between main object and joined object…

OK, but that's exactly the point: it's not clear to me what kind of object this is, because "beautiful", "natural" and "some geometry" can mean many things. ...especially when someone like me doesn't even realize what is actually in the picture. I also think it would be helpful if you shared your blend file.

This is a very simple setup. It’s a icosphere in geometry nodes with a Bézier curve randomly instanced on points in the normal’s axis of the ico.
Where instance (bezier) the object (ico) meets, it’s now a hard straight conjunction, like one is sticked on another.
With natural I mean a conjunction like a human hair coming out of the skin. If you have a close view on your skin, you’ll see a tiny organic growth structure around the hair. this would be my favorite look - hope i could explain it better

Basically, it is easier to build something that curves outwards instead of inwards, because otherwise the geometry would have to have a sufficiently high resolution to be able to depict these details. Is there a particular reason why you absolutely want to do this with GN instead of a shader (with which it would be easier and better to realize)?

Well, in the best case, if you really want to realize this under all circumstances with geometry nodes, the underlying geometry would need a sufficiently high resolution to be able to depict the desired details.
However, a simplified example with less high-resolution geometry could look like this:

Since I assume you somehow distribute the hair on the sphere using Distribute Points on Faces, you could directly select the closest points on the sphere based on the distance to these points, and move them slightly inwards. The Map Range node helps you to do this, allowing you to define the intensity and the area of effect.

That is a very good approach. Instead on moving them slightly inwards it should be also possible to move them slightly randomly. Using the „distribute“ points the effect should effect only the closer area around the instances, or not?
Many thanks for your input  it will help me further…

@smice Yes, correct, but you can of course also use the geometry of the hair directly as a target. The combination of Random Value and Map Range can then generate the variability.
